# Movement goes Slow After a period of time

Tags: c++, directx

hello every body : a problem in the issue of Player movement.

I have a Player character in empty scene moves from point A to B and returns to A in constant speed , At first hour of game running it was OKAY , After three Hours the movement became slow and slow , thank beforehand

Game.h

```
D3DXMATRIX  Player_Matrix ;         //main player matrix .
D3DXVECTOR3 PlayerPos;              //main player position .
D3DXVECTOR3 PlayerLook;             //main player Look at position .
```

Game.cpp

```
//Initialize()  
     D3DXMatrixIdentity(&Player_Matrix);    
     PlayerPos =  D3DXVECTOR3(10.0f,0.0f,10.0f);
     PlayerLook = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
```

.

```
//MovePlayer()    
        //declarations
        static float angle = D3DXToRadian(0);
        float Speed = 70.0f ;

       PlayerPos += ( PlayerLook * ( Speed * (m_timeDelta)) );      

       if(PlayerPos.x >= 320)         //      320:(B)
       {
            angle = D3DXToRadian(180);                  
       }
       if(PlayerPos.x <= 0)            //      0:(A)
       {
            angle = D3DXToRadian(180); 
       }


    //Setting up player matrixes
    D3DXMATRIX TransMat , RotMat , TempMat , ;  

    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&TempMat);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&RotMat);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&TransMat);  

    //Setup Rotation matrix .
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&RotMat,angle);
    angle = 0.0f ;

    //Attach PlayerLook Vector to rotation matrix
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&PlayerLook,&PlayerLook,&RotMat);

    //gathering rotation matrix with player matrix 
    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&Player_Matrix,&Player_Matrix,&RotMat);      

    //transmat is an empty matrix to collect new player position 
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&TransMat, PlayerPos.x,PlayerPos.y, PlayerPos.z);     

    //multiply new position matrix with main player matrix 
    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&TempMat,&Player_Matrix,&TransMat);

    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD,&TempMat);
    Main_Player->Render();
```

Comment: A memory leak is the usual explanation, it gets slow when the page faults start to add up.  In general, never depend on the game loop frequency, always use a clock that measures actual elapsed time.  And use a profiler.

Comment: A memory leak is a reasonable point if all the rendered scene is slow , but every thing is okay such as game loop , player animation delta time , time and frame rate ,just one thing goes slow is the movement .

Answer (score 0):

I would look into how you're calculating m_timeDelta. Perhaps your methodology is allowing floating point error to build up.

Here's an article on the subject: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/dont-store-that-in-a-float/

I'm with Tom Forsyth, and think that 64-bit integer is the best storage type for absolute times (http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/blog.wiki.html#[[A%20matter%20of%20precision]]), but double will work fine too.

Comment: `code Initialize() // Time stuff QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_time); m_starttime = (long double)m_time.QuadPart;`<br/> `code//start time for delta // code Render() //Game Delta Time  `QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_nowtime); m_timeDelta = ((long double)((m_nowtime.QuadPart - m_starttime)/m_ticks)); //Rest the variable with current time for Delta time calculation m_starttime = (long double)m_nowtime.QuadPart;

Comment: I think the formatting didn't work correctly for the comment but it looks to me like m_timeDelta is probably being calculated safely.

Comment: thanks "Columbo" , sure it works fine , rather than my PC is good for gaming (CPU I3 ,RAM 8GB , HDD 320GB  ) this problem happens while it doesn't on the others are lower such as (P4 , AMD)

Answer (score 0):

PlayerLook seems suspicious.

It is being iteratively rotated every frame, with floating point errors it's possible it might gradually be shrinking, probably only on the frames where the rotation changes.

You could confirm by looking at its value in the debugger after several hours of running, or you could eliminate it as a possibility if you renormalize it every frame and see if the slowdown disappears.

Comment: Yes , It is the exact answer I asked for , while I am executing the game under debugger It's going to be slow , in other word if I execute it under release It works normal after a while . but,  PlayerLook is a D3DXVECTOR3 which is struct of three floats (x=0,y=0,z=1) <br/> Ex: PlayerPos.z(250) += ( PlayerLook.z * ( 50.0f* (0.0004)) );  == 250+(1*50*0.0004) ==250+0.02 == 250.02 so the float type is enough  , for this I got confused .

Answer (score 0):

I've just found both the problem and its solution :

As I've explained before that all the App works fine ,  the problem is : the movement (just x++,y++,z++) gets slow and slow after a period of time . First I thought that it's a memory leak but the animation and delta time works fine .here, tried to find the reasonable problem that causes this .
I got the release of the App to other PC , after periods of time the App works fine , at that moment I saw the FPS won't reach 60.0 frame per sec , after search in MS DirectX SDK  inside DXUT I found a struct which control FPS , there a Doc that speaks about GPU and the acceleration , they advice to control FPS and its limitation , Here is the Code :

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: LockFrameRate()
// Desc: Limit The frame Rate to specified 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool LockFrameRate(int frame_rate , float SecPerCnt )
{
    static __int64 StartTime = 0 ;

    __int64 CurTime = 0 ; 
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&CurTime);

    float CurrentSecond = (float)((CurTime - StartTime )* SecPerCnt ) ;

    // Get the elapsed time by subtracting the current time from the last time
    // If the desired frame rate amount of seconds has passed -- return true (ie Blit())
    if( CurrentSecond > (1.0f / frame_rate) )
    {
        // Reset the last time
        StartTime = CurTime;    
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

// int WINAPI WinMain(....)

```
//***************************
    // Initialize Timing Preformance  . *
    //***************************

    //Store Counts per second 
    __int64 CountPerSec = 0 ; 

    //Gets how many counts does the CPU do per second 
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&CountPerSec); 

    //Gets second per count to preform it with different typs of CPUs
    float SecondPerCount = 1.0f / CountPerSec ; 

    //Initial Previous Time 
    __int64 PrevTime = 0 ;
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&PrevTime);

while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)                               // while not quit message , go on    
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0U,0U,PM_REMOVE))
        {                               
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else if(LockFrameRate(60 , SecondPerCount)) // If it is time to draw, do so , I selected 60 fps to limit
        {
            //Capture Current Time
            __int64 CurTime = 0 ;
            QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&CurTime);

            //Calculate Delta Time 
            float DeltaTime =(float) ((CurTime - PrevTime) * SecondPerCount)  ;         
            //Engine loop
            Engine->Engine_Run(DeltaTime , SecondPerCount );                        

            //After Frame Ends set Pervious Time to Current Time 
            PrevTime = CurTime ; 
        }
        //else
            //Sleep(1); // Give the OS a little bit of time to process other things
    }
```

I commented Sleep(1) because I know scientifically it's just a burden on the CPU but I put it for Scientific confidence , that's between App and other there is a idle proc that waits for each other this is in nowadays computer technologies .
if you want to try it you can feel some screen stops happens these are unwanted 
.

thank you  Stack Over Flow .
. thank you  guys  .